# Do we have inkscape program available in debian based base image

Tags: debian, docker, inkscape

I am creating a image and need to deploy it in docker container.
I have dependency of Inkscape in my project for converting svg to png .
I need to update my docker file as I need to add following command.

```
RUN APT-GET UPDATE && APT-GET INSTALL INKSCAPE
```

I am using python:3.10 as [base image link](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=3.10) my base image . Will it support to install the above package or I need to change it .
Chat Gpt is saying I need to change on the other hand bard.google.com is saying it will support ..

Comment: Aside from the capitalization being all wrong, why not test it yourself? It's not that difficult to create a test Dockerfile and build it

Comment: Ignore what chatGPT says. It is a *language model*, designed to *make beautiful sentences*, and trained for millions of computer hours until the sentences sound really good. it was not trained *at all* for making *correct sentences*. In other words, it's wrong, unless it was lucky.

Answer (score 1):

The `python:3.10` base image does not have `inkscape` installed by default.  To create a Docker image with `inkscape`, based on `python:3.10`, you would use a Dockerfile containing the statements

```
FROM python:3.10
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends inkscape
```

Note that the string after the `RUN` keyword is a Unix shell command, so the capitalisation is significant.

Answer (score 1):

Determining whether a given base image can provide a specific package requires up-to-date information, so LLMs can’t be relied upon to provide an accurate answer.

To find out the answer, it’s best to.tru it:

```
$ docker run -it --rm python:3.10
# apt-get update && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends inkscape
```

This downloads and installs Inkscape without error, so yes, `python:3.10` does make Inkscape available for installation. In a container descriptor you’d install it by adding

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends inkscape
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have dependency of Inkscape in my project for converting svg to png

Inkscape is not required for `svg` to `png`.

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y imagemagick
```

and in container:

```
convert -size 1024x1024 test.svg test.png
```

or

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y inkscape
```

and in container:

```
inkscape -w 1024 -h 1024 input.svg -o output.png
```